# How to get file instead of url with wGet

Tags: windows, http, cmd, wget, grib

I am using the following command in CMD.
`wget "http://gribs2.gmn-usa.com/cgi-bin/weather_fetch.pl?parameter=wind&days=7&region=NorthEurope&dataset=nww3"`

Wget download then a file with the name `weather_fetch.pl@parameter=wind&days=7&region=NorthEurope&dataset=nww3`.
When I'm using my webbrowser I'm getting the file `_cache_weather-cache_NorthEurope.wind.7days.grb.bz2`.

I need the second file, the first one is some gibberish. I tried to add the wait command but it did not work.

Comment: use the `-O` switch for output. `wget -O _cache_weather-cache_NorthEurope.wind.7days.grb.bz2 "http://gribs2.gmn-usa.com/cgi-bin/weather_fetch.pl?parameter=wind&days=7&region=NorthEurope&dataset=nww3"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wget` has a `-O` switch to specify the output filename.

a so command line would be:

```
wget -O _cache_weather-cache_NorthEurope.wind.7days.grb.bz2 "http://gribs2.gmn-usa.com/cgi-bin/weather_fetch.pl?parameter=wind&days=7&region=NorthEurope&dataset=nww3"
```

That however might not always be what is needed because it is a static name and each time you download the file, the old one is replaced. So depending on the purpose of the download, you can make it more dynamic by using a batch-file and adding a date to the filename:

```
@echo off
for /f %%i in ('powershell -command Get-Date -format "yyyyMMdd"') do (
   wget -O "%%~i_cache_weather-cache_NorthEurope.wind.7days.grb.bz2" "http://gribs2.gmn-usa.com/cgi-bin/weather_fetch.pl?parameter=wind&days=7&region=NorthEurope&dataset=nww3"
)
```

which, considering today's date, will result in a filename of:

```
20210516_cache_weather-cache_NorthEurope.wind.7days.grb.bz2
```